# Upload images in .Net Core Why this code not work?

Tags: c#, .net, image-uploading

I have a problem with testing the api with postman. When I try to post image my response is:
 "message": "Something went wrong. Please contact support!",
    "statusCode": 400
The request just make a folder usersImages.

```cs
[HttpPost("{username}")]
public IActionResult UploadPhoto(string username, [FromForm] IFormFile photo)
{
    try
    {
        var user = _userService.GetCurrentUser(username);
        if (user == null)
            return NotFound();

        var path = Path.Combine(_hosting.WebRootPath, "usersImages");
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(photo.FileName);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

        photo.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
        user.ImageUrl = fileName;
        _userService.UpdateUser(user);

        return Ok(user);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var error = new ErrorViewModel("Something went wrong. Please contact support!", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        return new JsonResult(error) { StatusCode = error.StatusCode };
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exception that you are catching in the `catch` block? That should give you more information about what's going on.

Comment: Also, it's a bad idea to declare an `Exception` variable in a `catch` block and _not use it_. If you're capturing the exception information, _use it_.

Comment: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I just change that

Comment: Can you figure out which line is causing that exception to be thrown? What variable is null that you are trying to access?

Comment: Think  fileName but I don't no why

Comment: Do you know how to set breakpoints in your application? Can you walk through your code line by line as its executing to investigate the values of each variable?

Comment: Try removing `[FromForm]`.  Not that I know for sure that is the problem, but I've never seen that attribute used on File Uploads, and file uploads are sort of a tricky form element.  Not exactly a normal "form" element, so I wouldn't be surprised if that was causing photo to just be null.

Comment: Removing [From Form] and now work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `[FromForm]` attribute on your file upload variable.  Although the upload is part of the form, the file uploads are a sort of special case in which the data for them isn't contained in the serialized form, and are stored in a separate section of the multi-part form element.